# Django server won't run: This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect

Tags: python, django, cs50, web-development-server, commerce

I am trying to make an auction website for my CS50W project2: Commerce .When I try to run `python3 manage.py runserver`. There are 6 errors. I get that the system identified 6 errors:

```
System check identified 6 issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 486, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 259, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auctions.0003_auto_20201114_0509 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auctions', '0002_listing')
```

please help

Comment: did you delete the auctions 0002_listing migration file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've messed up with migrations (probably removed a migration which was already applied).

In case you don't actually have any important data in your database and it's OK for you to recreate a database, I'd recommend the next:

1. Drop/create your database.
2. Delete all migration files (in `migrations` directory inside each application)
3. Recreate migrations `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. Apply migrations `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Another option is to edit the `0003_auto_20201114_0509.py` migration file and replace the `0002_listing` with the name of the first migration file in this application. Though, it's a dirty solution which potentially may have consequences later. If possible, I'd recommend to recreate the database and migrations.

Comment: @R12345 then you may mark this response as a correct one.